# Browser or code wrong? Web Sql doesnt create table

Tags: javascript, web-sql

The table it isn't created or does not show:

```
function createTbl(){
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)');
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO data(name) VALUES("Someone")');
    });
}
```

The database is there, but on Tables it's empty.
My code isn't wrong I believe...Is that browser issues?

Comment: You should add the browser you're using to your question.

Comment: SORRY! Google Chrome/Safari up-to-date.

Comment: This is why error handling is important.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't working because of the keyword PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT, instead use the keyword UNIQUE. Also do not club Unique and AUTO_INCREMENT.
Here is a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>

    function runExample(){
      webSql(processResultSet);
    }

    function webSql(callback) {
      var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id INTERGER AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES ("someone")');
      });

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM data', [], function(tx, results) {
          callback(results);
        });
      });
    }

    function processResultSet(results) {
      console.dir(results);
      var len = results.rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        console.dir(results.rows.item(i));
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="runExample()">
</body>
</html>
```